# Publish geoprocessing service on AWS ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, postgis, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, amazon-web-services

I'm planning to use the following stack on Amazon AWS:
- Esri ArcGIS Enterprise 10.5 on Ubuntu with Postgresql (Dec 2016)

Can be found on this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N5HOYPC?qid=1484816439886&sr=0-7&ref_=srh_res_product_title

After enabling ArcGIS Server Enterprise and PostGIS with SDE, will I be able to publish an ArcPy geoprocessing service into the ArcGIS Server?

Will I be able to run ArcPy commands using the PostGIS data?

Actually, my goal is to have a RESTful api in ArcGIS Server with Python and ArcPy backend to manipulate the spatial data.

If this is not possible, what else could I do only using AWS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of sub-questions, so to tackle answering this, I have referenced a number of articles for further reference to get you started.

> Will I be able to publish an ArcPy geoprocessing service into the
>   ArcGIS Server

Yes. [Please refer to Authoring geoprocessing tasks with Python scripts.](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/what-s-new-in-arcgis-for-server.htm)  This topic goes into some considerations when building a script that you intend on publishing to the ArcGIS GIS Server

> Will I be able to run ArcPy commands using the PostGIS data?

ArcPy is installed with ArcGIS Server, and you can run scripts from that machine independently of publishing the scripts to ArcGIS Server if you so wish.  For example a python script that runs as a scheduled task to perform some sort of data cleansing exercise.

> my goal is to have a RESTful api in ArcGIS Server with Python and
>   ArcPy backend to manipulate the spatial data.

This is entirely achievable.  Develop and test your python script in the ArcGIS Desktop environment.  You can then publish this to the ArcGIS GIS Server which exposes the capabilities and input parameters required to run the script via the [GIS REST Services Directory](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_rest.html).   Also take a look at the new [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/overview-of-the-ArcGIS-Python-API/) which is also included on that box by default.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I also realize that  "Amazon AWS: - Esri ArcGIS Enterprise 10.5 on Ubuntu with Postgresql (Dec 2016)" is an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) which turns into an ec2 (Elastic Compute Cloud) instance after you turn it on. That means that you have access to it as if you had a real hardware server and you can do whatever you want with it. For example, when you publish a python geoprocessing service, it will be stored in a specific folder of the instance and then, this script can access the local database of the server.